# jQuery UI dialog-form input fields not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I am new to J-query UI and Javascript. In my HTML page there is an EDIT USER button. If i click EDIT USER button,jQuery UI [dialog-form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) will open.Dialog-form consists of input fields(text fields,select fields).Values for input fields in dialog-form will be dynamically appended.

Its perfectly working in browser(desktop) but in mobile, input fields dialog-form cannot be focused.if i tap the text field ,dialog-form moving up and down.if i tab select field mobile shows blank screen.

**Script which I have been added :**

```
 <script src="../js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

**Dialog-form looks like :**

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit User" >  
          <form>
                <fieldset>

                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="UserName" disabled="disabled" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large" />
                  <input type="text" id="UserId" style="display:none;"/>

                  <label>Staff Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="StaffName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large" />

                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input type="text" id="PassWord" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large" />

                  <label>Imei No</label>
                  <input type="text" id="ImeiNo" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-large"/>

                  <label>User Role</label>
                  <select id="userroles" ><option value="Select UserRoles">Select UserRoles</option>
                  </select><br/>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
</div>
```

**Dialog-form initializing :**

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {
            submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {                         
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {                       
           $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }

});
```

can any one help me.?

Comment: Try including jquery-ui mobile support: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Here works fine on mobile (iPhone 5) http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Bbspy/

Comment: @lzzey : i forget to add it.i already include touchpunch.

Comment: @ Irvin Dominin aka Edward : did u check in your mobile.?it works in desktop browser but in mobile it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes on safari mobile iOS 7 works fine on jsfiddle; do you have other script/css rules that can break the dialog on mobile?

Comment: @ Irvin Dominin aka Edward thanks for ur reply...does jquery UI dialog work in android 2.2.?

Comment: i think so its version problem..

Comment: @ Irvin Dominin aka Edward : thanks a lot..its working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

After some serious testing on mobile and surfing on internet ,I found that Bootstrap modals and jQuery UI dialog-form will not work correctly(perfectly) on older version of Android mobile.